# Python SyntaxError: EOF while scanning triple-quoted string literal

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

My script is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
RAW_ZIP = """PK    šîF4“àµÑ$=   tcp_host.exeì]
|GßË]È%\Èa/íµMáŠ¦%ElÀBê…|bÜåÈ”#ƒMIzÙ£¡†<¢\·±¨UQ«©ZµjU´ÑÖh©´”ZªhQ—ÛôB¡œÿ7³{ùÀ¶~ýüéÁììÌ¼yó%ô6“›¸ŸIÖÃ%,…N–*§xŒ4xF*ÓÎžŒÎd.•8¹l¹ j'4ŸZëí‚R;»‰MÊiÈL`
...long string...
"Ýä­+\è\n$NKƒ—u-Èp‰f(OY3ò ˆh&‚"¾ ôE\>Ó]lÀY˜ *¸|ÐZV=Èø4«›„×‹³\1òNDØø†R¼pžH5ÇHeòÓêxtŠ‹‰Yí2tªÖE˜"&-')r¢Wå¯AÏk"Õhv%r³\ã&·ù$šR¹ª6ñÕ«›ûP¨6³ÍÍý§ŽÚˆœÛ¢|Øâbý63>8£zŠn`–DÞøUâV“cO§E©¸z½õ—OùÛª|ä‹P‘[¾†ä9ÝGrŠüšK(EöŒíj»<£>M|ù^–¿¦Pß8¯Òw‘é’*3ŸÖh†¬®˜‹µ[]T°³CxÝ­»âUŸ³Ê"RzY,ûŽ—o È#H¶®’ˆ“
>ÑaËm1èØ÷‰ )ô§ìKvÐ
c"""
```

But when i run it i get the error:

```
SyntaxError: EOF while scanning triple-quoted string literal
```

Why?

Comment: Works fine for me on Python 2 and 3.

Comment: well, are you SURE there aren't `"""` that naturally appear in that garbage?

Comment: Can we see the whole garbage in a pastebin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reason: Python thinks that within your string the file ends.

Guessing: For some reason character 26 is EOF in some cases.

Motivation:
Python files are text files whereas zip files are binary. You should not mix them because

- the text files have an encoding whereas binary files do not.
- in Windows, Mac and Linux line endings are different. Text files may be changed accordingly.

In both cases zip binary stuff will break.

Solution:
Encoding.

```
>>> import base64
>>> base64.b64encode(b"""raw string""") # here you get the encoded result
b'cmF3IHN0cmluZw==' 
>>> base64.b64decode(b'cmF3IHN0cmluZw==') # this is part of your Python file.
b'raw string'
```